# SQL - where clause matching only one condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need help writting a query. Using this schema as example:

```
Table: A
id 1
id 2

Table: ALocalized
A_id 1, culture 1, name 'EN translation'
A_id 1, culture 2, name 'PT translation'
A_id 2, culture 1, name 'EN translation'
```

This is the schema i'm using to localize information. Each record on **A** has at least one related record on **ALocalized**, but there may be some rows who don't have a localized record for certain cultures.

In this example, i want to query **A** and filter the **ALocalized** by culture 2. If culture 2 doesn't exist, then return any other available.
The result should be:

```
A_id 1, culture 2, name 'PT translation'
A_id 2, culture 1, name 'EN translation'
```

I've tried to do this joining both tables, using an sub query but i think that my problem is in **where** clause.

```
where (ALocalized.culture = @cultureparameter OR ALocalized.culture = 1 OR ALocalized.culture = 2) limit 1
```

When @cultureparameter is 2 returns culture 1. It isn't respecting the order of where clauses

How should i do this? I was trying to avoid the use of loops to check each **A** record for an existence of **ALocalized**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look for the mysql equivalent od SQL Server's COALLESCE function

Comment: Fortunately mysql does have coalesce :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*,
        COALESCE(b.culture, c.culture) Culture,
        COALESCE(b.Name, c.Name) Name
FROM    tableA a
        LEFT JOIN   tableB b
            ON a.id = b.a_id AND
                b.culture = 2
        LEFT JOIN   tableB c
            ON a.id = c.a_id AND
                c.culture = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd407/3)

Comment: Based on your answer i've used a case for each culture to change the order on coalesce. Thanks